Login Screen Unresponsive After Entering Password
Running Ubuntu 22.04, I've been encountering a weird problem recently.
The login screen presents itself but gets stuck when password is entered. I need to ctrl-alt-F1 to switch to the first virtual console, click "not listed", enter my username and password from there in order to login again.
LSB Version:    core-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:printing-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch:security-11.1.0ubuntu4-noarch
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy

Wonder what is causing the issue. Hopefully an upgrade to the latest LTS will fix this.
